# RecyclerView with another RecyclerView as viewType

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Is it considered bad design to use a RecyclerView as a ViewType of another RecyclerView? Say vertical RecyclerViewCad has 9 different view types, one of which needs to be a horizontal list. What might be the drawbacks of making that view type itself a RecyclerView, say RecyclerViewVase?

Comment: I've done it several times this way. Also with other Widgets inside the recycler like ViewPager.
Never had any problems, just keep your models well organzied.

Comment: Wow! ViewPager as viewType that's insane! Doesn't it get too heavy or such? Does your UI never complain? This is good to hear. Thanks.

Comment: Everything works smooth ;) But keep an extra eye about the 'onBind' function to do only adapter rebindings to your pagers etc when it's really necessary. First time i have tried to code 'lightweight' widgets, this will end in having x custom widgets that are all untestet etc . So i sticked with the default widgets.

Comment: Cool! Do you mind reposting as a response so I may check this thread as answered? It may help someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho, this is not a problem if you keep an extra eye at your 'onBind' functions.
In case of a inner recyclerview this means, do only a adapter rebinding if the viewholder is really bound to a different model (recycled).

I've done it many times this way, also using other widgets such as viewpager.

On the other hand, some widgets are really heavy, such as a videoplayer, in that case i handle it with a single instance player and de/attaching it to the active viewholder.

Hope this helps.